# How can I identify the minimum value that satisfies a condition in each year?

Tags: r

My data frame has degree_day and mean_temp values for each day from 1939-2020. For each year, I'd like to find the day where degree_days surpasses 186.77 and identify the mean_temp on that day. Then I want to find the average of the mean_temp on the day when degree_days surpasses 186.77 across all years.

```
year <- c(1939,1939,1939, 1940,1940,1940)

degree_days <- c(184,187,190,185,189,190)

mean_temp <- c(14,15,16,10,11,12)
```

I want to find the average mean_temp from the minimum value of degree_days that surpasses 186.77 in each year. Here this would be the average of 15 and 11.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `findInterval` after doing a group by

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     group_by(year) %>% 
     slice(findInterval(186.77, degree_days) + 1)
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 2 x 3
# Groups:   year [2]
#   year degree_days mean_temp
#  <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>
#1  1939         187        15
#2  1940         189        11
```

---

Or another option is `which` with `>=`

```
df1 %>% 
    group_by(year) %>% 
    slice(which(degree_days >= 186.77)[1])
```

---

In order to get the `mean` across all 'year'

```
df1 %>% 
     group_by(year) %>% 
     slice(which(degree_days >= 186.77)[1]) %>% 
     ungroup %>%
     mutate(mean_temp_all_year = mean(mean_temp))
# A tibble: 2 x 4
#   year degree_days mean_temp mean_temp_all_year
#  <dbl>       <dbl>     <dbl>              <dbl>
#1  1939         187        15                 13
#2  1940         189        11                 13
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(year, degree_days, mean_temp)
```

Comment: @Nicole I showed two options based on the example you showed.  Both of them are working fine for me

Comment: @Nicole is this error based on a different example?

Comment: the second example worked great! thank you so so much